# Show message in excel when connection is not available

Tags: sql-server, excel-2007

I'm connecting to SQL Server 2005 using connection string in Excel 2007. I'd like to give the same excel to my client who doesn't have access to our database. Now is it possible to show a meaningful message and be able to retain the data? I have written code on command button click.

Answer (score 0):

yes thats possible. Try using something like this

```
    On Error Goto ErrHandler

---Your Connection Code Here ----

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Cannot Establish Connection.", vbExclamation
```